# Did the Sponge Bob movie try to recruit David Attenborough?

Tags: production, spongebob-squarepants

The opening of the The SpongeBob Movie: Sponge on the Run movie has a narrator that seems to be [joking with a David Attenborough voice](https://spongebob.fandom.com/wiki/Documentary_narrator).

Did they inquire if the real David Attenborough could have done the narration? If so, what was his answer?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an authoritative answer, but I highly doubt it.

The show's regular narrator, known only as "[French Narrator](https://spongebob.fandom.com/wiki/French_Narrator)", is an homage to marine biologist and documentary filmmaker [Jacques-Yves Cousteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Cousteau), one of Hillenburg's inspirations. I expect that the narrator from *Sponge on the Run* was similarly intended to be an homage to Attenborough, another man famous for wildlife documentaries. Getting the *real* Attenborough to voice him would defeat the purpose of paying homage to him.